# EF Core 8 preview version raw SQL queries for unmapped types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We have to call the stored procedure from .NET 6 API using raw SQL in EF Core 8 preview. It was working fine if all the properties which have public sets in the SQL query ie stored procedure.

But in a few scenarios, we want to pull only a sub-set of columns, but still want to use the same model. However, in this case, an error was thrown:

> The required column 'colname' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.but we want to solve without all public properties present in the query.

This is my method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecStoredProc<T>(string procName,IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
        try
        {
            var inputParameter = new List<SqlParameter>(parameters.Count);

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                inputParameter.Add(new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = parameter.Key,
                    Value = parameter.Value ?? DBNull.Value
                });
            }

            string procWithParameter = string.Format("exec {0} {1}", procName, string.Join(", ", inputParameter.Select(p => p.ParameterName)));

            var result = _dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<T> (procWithParameter, inputParameter.ToArray());

            return result.ToList();
            //return result.ToList();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if is acceptable in your project, but I found usefull to use [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/query) to query the database, and let EF the managements of entity.  This type of approach is tipically used in CQRS pattern (where queries are managed differently from commands), and is used in architecture examples by MS (such as [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers)).  You could use `dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()` to get the connection, and then call the [`Query`](https://dapper-tutorial.net/result-strongly-typed) extension method.

Answer (score 1):

In EF you need to define an Type for each query result.  It can be a Keyless Entity, or with [EF Core 8 an arbitrary type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/plan#sql-queries-for-unmapped-types), but you can't just run an arbitrary SQL query and use the results.

And when materializing query results EF change tracking doesn't track whether you've loaded individual properties of an Entity, which would add a perf and complexity cost for little benefit.

Use Dapper or ADO.NET if you don't have an Entity that matches the result.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft - this is no longer required with EF Core 8

Comment: The target type no longer needs to be registered with the DbContext.  Updated answer.

Comment: ok but in my case, I am using a stored procedure it will return different kind of result set based on input parameters it will work fine when I am using EF 6 Raw Sql Query. the method was SqlQuery am calling this.Database.SqlQuery<T>(procWithParameter, inputParameter.ToArray()).but now I am migrating into .net 6 with ef core 8 it will not work as expected because it throws The required column 'colname' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation. we want to achieve this using ef core 8 without dapper or Ado.

Comment: We're running into the same problem. Any idea why EF Core 8 REQUIRES every property to be retrieved in the query, but EF 6 does not? It seems like a silly restriction to not allow us to add properties to the class where data is not retrieved by the query.